# How to format a table to show better when pulling data from mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql

I am having issues trying to display the data in the console.. i just want  it to show organized or close to organized. This is how i am pulling the data

```
 // Loop through the result set
       while( rs.next() )
       {
          System.out.print( rs.getInt(1) ) ;
          System.out.print("   |   ");
          System.out.print( rs.getString(2) );
          System.out.print("   |   ");
          System.out.print( rs.getString(3) );
       }
```

but this data shows all over the place like this..

```
  123 Blaah St   |   Apt 2A   |   FL   
  Fort   |   null   |   FL   
  5601 N Dixie Hwy   |   null   |   FL
```

Is there a good advise to format this better in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `System.out.format`.

Example:

```
String format = "|%1$-10s|%2$-10s|%3$-20s|\n";
System.out.format(format, "Short", "Other", "Field");
System.out.format(format, "Very long", "", "Text");
System.out.format(format, "Long too!", ":)", "Bye");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print` on the last line of the while loop, so you get a new line for each record.

Answer (score 0):

while adding, check the max size of the input String , then add a padding with respect to that size of the String among each pair or column